# Need to generate an json array, then loop through the values

Tags: asp.net, javascript, json

I need to create some sort of a state for a bunch of elements on a page.
The stats can be 1 or -1.

Now on the server side I will generate a JSON array and put it in my .aspx page like this:

```
var someArray = { 100:-1, 1001:1, 102:1, 103:-1 }
```

How do I loop through each value now in javascript?

BTW, is my JSON array format correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `someArray` is a misnomer as it is actually an Object. To loop through it, though:

```
for(key in someArray) {
    alert(someArray[key]);
}
```

As far as whether it is valid, the above works for me but I believe technically keys should be strings:

```
{
    "100": -1,
    "1001": 1,
    "102": 1,
    "103": -1 
}
```

[Check out this handy JSON validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Comment: now working? It shouldn't be working. You're confusing arrays with objects, which are not the same thing.